# Calculating a graph from a skeletonized image

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I would like to find the joints and the segments from a image that looks like a graph after skeletonize it. I need the number of both joint and the length of the segments.

Do you know what are the best approach for it?

Thanks

Here is the image explanation:

[image]

Original image:

[image]

Binary:
[image]

Skeleton:
[image]

Comment: haven't tried to do anything like this, but it looks a bit like a Voronoi diagram.  if you could fit a set of points to the middle of each dark area, there should be standard algorithms to calculate your "joints" and "segments".  if you could say what this is an image of you might get suggestions from people who know the literature better!

Comment: You should provide the skeleton image.

Comment: @SamMason: chance are high that the Voronoi diagram constructed on the "centers" will have a different topology than the skeleton. And a direct approach of edge following seems easier.

Comment: @PabloCastilla could you post the original image and the binary image without annotations for testing ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza thanks for answering, I have updated the question as you requested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your skeletonization algorithm works well, the joints are pixels surrounded by three or four neighbors, while the edges pixels have only two. Free endpoints have only one.

A possible approach is to scan the image in search of all junctions and endpoints and create graph vertices for each. Label these pixels with the vertex indexes.

Then for every joint/endpoint, follow all the incident edges until you reach another joint/endpoint. Add the corresponding graph edge.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. I have to dilate after skeletonize to have a connected skeleton, is this normal?

Comment: @PabloCastilla: is the posted image *after* dilation ?

Comment: Yes it is. Without the dilation I have a lot of holes, it wouldn't have any path

Comment: @PabloCastilla: can you post the undilated image (without resizing) ?

Comment: @YvesDoust, ok, after generating the file without resizing it seems perfect in the file. I have changed the image in the post, but I think your idea will be feasible right now. Thanks!

Comment: As for dilation to connect paths after skeletonization - no, shouldn't be the case. As for the proposed idea, good in theory, doesn't work in practice, because it depends heavily on the connectivity neighborhood of the skeletonization algorithm. I have tested this as well, using different skeletonization approaches and always ended up having nodes where none should be, because there are special cases of pixels having 3+ neighbors along a path without any split or intersection.

Comment: Also depending on the skeletonization you will get node clusters at intersections. More severe however are node clusters along paths without splitting.

Comment: @Mär: make sure to use a skeletonization algorithm such that the neighbors of a pixel cannot be 4-connected. There are two attitudes in life: making it work or making it fail.